# TODO comment font color in VS2010 with ReSharper and Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, todo, productivity-power-tools

I just installed the Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010. I also have ReSharper installed. Prior to the PowerTools installation, my TODO comments (i.e. `// TODO: Do Something`) were showing up in the code using the font listed under VS options as "Resharper Todo Item". Now it's a dark blue color, and apparently ignoring the setting in the VS options.

I'm using a dark theme, so I can barely read these comments. I've dug through all the options I can find (all of the options in VS options including the new power tools options, and in the ReSharper options), and can't find it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To change the colour of the TODO items in the text editor, change the environment settings using Visual Studio (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors)

Then scroll to the item in the "Display items" list which in this case is "Resharper TODO item"

UPDATE: this applies to Resharper **7.1** and **8.2 upwards** as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312785/todo-comment-font-color-in-vs2010-with-resharper-and-productivity-power-tools#comment-38277615)

For Resharper **8 < 8.2** please [see the solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094592/161457) by **@Soeholm**

Comment: I need to remember to scroll *past* the checked answer and look at other replies before trying. This had a 4:1 acceptance but I did the other method before reading this. :/ This is the proper solution.

Comment: I can't find any display items with the name Resharper in them :-(

Comment: Have you got 'Text Editor' selected in the 'Show settings for:' dropdown?

Comment: Perhaps its changed in the latest version of Resharper? The setting I've described is in version 7.1

Comment: Perhaps, I'm using Resharper 8.0.1

Comment: this is a pre-version 8 solution - for resharper 8 see answer by @Soeholm - and yes, it could be different for version 9 when that comes out too...

Comment: This happened to me in VS2010 after I installed Xamarin. I have version 8.2.1 of Resharper. I had to go to Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Resharper Todo Item and change one of the values (I changed the background from Default to some color), then OK, then bring up Fonts and Colors again, scrolled down to the Resharper Todo Item, then set the background back to Default (probably doesn't matter what setting you change) and OK again. That worked for me.

Comment: @cordal any idea why other keywords like BUG and NotImplemented are defined to show different colours in Resharper but VS always shows the same colour as TODO which is dark blue. And I can't even find Resharper Bug in VS->Tool->Option->Environment->Font and Color->Display Item though I can find Resharper Todo there.

Comment: In resharper 10 and up the setting can be changed via Options -> Tools -> To-do Items. Either change the color or delete the option from the list

Comment: FYI, this doesn't change the color in the todo explorer.  For that, go to the Resharper Menu-Options-Tools-To do Explorer-Todo-Edit

Answer (score 46):

I had this problem with Resharper 8.0.1 and none of the other answers helped me since "Resharper TODO item" did not show up in the list.

I found a solution to the problem here:

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation

1. Close all Visual Studio instances
2. Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS version}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged file
3. Type anything there
4. Save the file
5. Open VS and check Fonts and Colors in Tools | Options | Environment

Hope this helps any Resharper 8 users :-)

Comment: Thanks!  Had to change the security on the file in order to edit.

Comment: thanks, the marked answer doesn't work for v8, but this one does

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved now, and the accepted answer works in R# 8.2.1

Comment: Please always include the real solution in your answer, not just a link. Links die, and then your information will be lost in space...

Comment: @Soeholm Thanks for updating your answer with the necessary steps!

Comment: This solved my problem! 
You don't have to modify the file, just save it so the filestamp gets updated.

Answer (score 18):

Did you try this dialog? (Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Todo items) near the bottom

[image]

Comment: I didn't see that screen even existed - the "Edit" button didn't activate when I clicked on "Todos", but double-clicking the item brought it up - weird. Regardless, that didn't change anything, but now the comments are magically matching the normal "ReSharper Todo Item" color from the regular options, so I'm all good now. Maybe my machine just needed a reboot to flush itself out.

Comment: @wal, unfortunately the colour settings you refer to and illustrate only apply to the colour of the To-do items in the ReSharper To-do window, not the actual comments used for the items.

Comment: cheers, updated my answer with a redirect to the correct answer

Comment: Do you know why Bug and Note are shown as the same colour as TODO in comments even though they are defined to show different colours (as can be seen in your screenshot)?

Comment: Removing the "TODO" item in the R->O->Tools->Todo items window works for me -- makes TODO look like a regular comment. Not ideal perhaps but...

Answer (score 8):

If it will help to someone, I found one more collision with the TODO thing in Visual Studio 2010. It happens when **VSCommands** extensions is installed. To fix the TODO colouring,

1. go to  `Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors`.
2. Find **VSCommands.Comment.Todo** in the Display Items list.
3. Fix the colouring ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your Visual Studio does not have the settings for ReSharper colors in the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts And Colors you may be able to get them back by deleting the cache from the registry.

For VS 2013 the cache is located in the registry at:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\FontAndColors\Cache

VS2012 cache is located at
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FontAndColors\Cache

These both need to be reset seperately

Backing up then deleting the entire cache folder fixed the issue for me so that next time I started VS 2013 I had the ReSharper color settings available.

Comment: This solution works on VS2013 Update 5 + ReSharper Ultimate 10.

Answer (score 0):

The VSCommands plugin can also change this. But since their default color for "TODO" is red, not blue, it's probably not what is affecting you. That being said, in addition to Genius' reply above, there is a dedicated page on "Comments Formatting" in VSCommands here: [Visual Studio 2010 Red Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152711/visual-studio-2010-red-comments).